# VueJS - @click not adding listener/working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Sorry for being a bit newbie at Vue. I'm trying to find out why one of my click functions is not triggering for multiple elements.

The click IS WORKING on the #app-icon. However, the function is not triggering (or even adding an event listener) for either of the labels.

I have a based HTML structure:

```
<header id="topbar">
    <div id="app-menu">
        <i id="app-icon" @click="clickEffect($event)" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        <form id="searchVideos" action="#" method="POST">
            <label>
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                <input v-on:keyup="ChangeVideos" type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search anything">
            </label>
            <label class="label-videos" @click="clickEffect($event)" id="videos-mine">
                <input type="radio" checked name="search-val">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </label>
            <label class="label-videos" v-on:click="clickEffect($event)" id="videos-all">
                <input type="radio" name="search-val">
                <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            </label>
        </form>
        <div class="login">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

and my VueJS script:

```
var buttonClick = new Vue({
    el: '#topbar',
    data: {
        clicked: false,
    },
    methods: {
        clickEffect: (event) => {
            console.log(1);
            let el = event.target;
            el.classList.add("clicked");
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.classList.remove("clicked");
            }, 500);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: check your html in your browser inspector, the "clicked" class is actually added then remove to your labels (i tested it in fiddle and it works)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your codes should work for `clicked` effect.

But you should fix the **Arrow function (lambda)** usage for Vue methods, it will cause the context of that method is not Vue instance if **using Arrow function (lambda)**.

Look into below snippet (check the console output for clickEffect/clickEffect1 when click 'Test'):

```js
var buttonClick = new Vue({
    el: '#topbar',
    data: {
        clicked: false,
    },
    methods: {
        clickEffect: function(event) {
            console.log('function', this.$data)
            let el = event.target;
            el.classList.add("clicked");
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.classList.remove("clicked");
            }, 1500);

        },
        clickEffect1: (event) => {
            console.log('lambda', this.$data)
        },
        ChangeVideos: function () {
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<header id="topbar">
    <div id="app-menu">
        <i id="app-icon" @click="clickEffect($event);clickEffect1()" class="fa fa-bars">Test</i>
        <form id="searchVideos" action="#" method="POST">
            <label>
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                <input v-on:keyup="ChangeVideos" type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search anything">
            </label>
            <label class="label-videos" @click="clickEffect($event)" id="videos-mine">
                <input type="radio" checked name="search-val">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </label>
            <label class="label-videos" v-on:click="clickEffect($event)" id="videos-all">
                <input type="radio" name="search-val">
                <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            </label>
        </form>
        <div class="login">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Sorry but, What's Lambda?

Comment: @ConorReid check [Javascript Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) hah, my bad. It seems it is called **Arrow function** not lambda...